# problem in uploading the code

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

```
Sketch uses 12452 bytes (38%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 970 bytes (47%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1078 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Have you been able to upload before or did this problem occur all of a sudden?

Comment: Also like mentioned in the ide you should increase verbosity during upload. Maybe there are some hints where to look for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Try to upload your code without any device connected to Uno. Disconnect all IO pins. Upload the code via onboard USB port.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no proper communication between the IDE and your Arduino. The reason can be many things:

- RX/TX UART port used
- USB port broken
- USB cable broken
- Arduino broken
- USB port drivers not properly installed
- Problem inside IDE
- ...

To troubleshoot you could try:

- Disconnect RX/TX jumpers
- Try another USB port
- Remove other USB devices
- Try another USB cable
- Try another Arduino
- Try another PC/laptop
- Reinstall IDE
- Reinstall USB drivers